# set object properties in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this snippet below (with this valid case, where `x.size` exists):

```js
let x = {
  "size": 123
}

let y = {
  'size': null
}

try {
  y.size = parseFloat(x.size) ? `${parseFloat(x.size)}` : `${x.size}`;
} catch (e) {
  console.log("yes")
  y.size = null;
}

console.log(y)
```

But I was expecting in case the property `x.size` is missing to enter on catch, and set `y.size` to `null`, but I get:

`{ size: undefined }`

```js
let x = {
}

let y = {
  'size': null
}

try {
  y.size = parseFloat(x.size) ? `${parseFloat(x.size)}` : `${x.size}`;
} catch (e) {
  console.log("yes")
  y.size = null;
}

console.log(y)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your time!

Comment: `x` exists and is an object, so there's no problem accessing its properties. `x.size` is indeed `undefined` and there's nothing wrong with accessing or writing to it. If you want to test for its presence, use `'size' in x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `catch` block will only execute if an error is thrown in the `try` block.

Comment: So in which case my code will throw an error inside `try`? I tried by removing the `size` property or by setting it to `Nan`, `undefined`, `null`.. and nothing is working

Comment: in your current implementation, it will not throw an error. you could explicitly throw one yourself, but this is probably not best practice. you could just have the "else" part of your ternary operator set y.size to `null` instead of `x.size`, which is undefined. then you could remove the `try/catch` and just have the ternary operator on its own take care of setting `y.size`

Answer (score 1):

Well `parseFloat(undefined)` gives `NaN`, so you'll go to the "else" part of the `? :`. That will interpolate that `undefined` value into a string, so you get the string `undefined`.

Accessing an undefined property of an object does not throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code. Output is correct.
Explanation:

```
try {
    y.size = parseFloat(x.size) ? `${parseFloat(x.size)}` : `${x.size}`;
} catch (e) {
    console.log("yes")
    y.size = null;
}

// when x.size => undefined => which is converted to string using `tempate literal` to  "undefined" 

// Output
{
  "size": "undefined"
}
```

Right Solution:
If you want `null` value of undefined value:

```
let y = {
    'size': null
}

try {
    y.size = parseFloat(x.size) ? `${parseFloat(x.size)}` : x.size ? x.size : null;
} catch (e) {
 // This will be required if any error occurs so catch block will add property to y object
    console.log("yes")
    y.size = null;
}

console.log(y)

Output:
// Output
{
  "size":  null
}
```